# UITextField with leftViewMode UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing remains visible while editing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a UITextField subclass object and leftView with `leftViewMode` set to `UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing`. However, the left view **remains visible during editing** until the user enters at least one character.

*Before entering text:*

[image]

*After entering Text:*

[image]

**Questions:**

1. Is this behavior expected and documented? How can I ensure that the
2. left view is invisible during editing, before any character is
   entered?

Comment: This isn't the expected behavior. If you're using a custom subclass of `UITextField`, please post the relevant code.

Comment: @jlehr -- I was able to reproduce the issue with a vanilla UITextField.

Comment: @Justin Really? How?

Comment: @jlehr I have a bare `UITextField` in a XIB. In my case, I set `rightView` to an empty `UIView` with a solid background color for testing. I set `rightViewMode` to `UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing`. Nonetheless, when I first tap the empty field to focus it, `rightView` remains visible. I've received all of the editing delegate callbacks, so I know the field considers itself "editing." As soon as I enter a character, it disappears. 

Did you test this, yourself, with a different outcome?

Comment: @Justin, Yep, and I couldn't reproduce the described behavior, so perhaps there's some specific setup required to trigger the problem.

Comment: @jlehr I just created a brand new project with only a `UITextField` in a XIB and and three lines of code to set `rightView`. The problem reproduced exactly. [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/jkaufman/8fa653fd6ab9221830e2) with the relevant code. Perhaps _you've_ performed some setup that the original author and I need to.

Comment: @jlehr [Here is a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/kurm3lx.png). If you discover a discrepancy between our projects, please post your solution as an answer so that I can award the bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In answer to your questions:

1. Yes, that appears to be expected `UITextField` behavior, though it's not clearly spelled out in any official documentation that I could find.
2. You can further customize the default behavior by implementing `UITextFieldDelegate` methods to, for example, remove the overlay view as soon as editing begins, even if the text field is empty.

For example, let's assume you defined a property to hold a strong reference to a custom overlay view:

```
@interface ViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *customView;

@end
```

You could then configure the overlay view and register for delegate notifications in `viewWillAppear:`, as shown below:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 30.0)];
    self.customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    self.textField.leftView = self.customView;
    self.textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing;

    self.textField.delegate = self;
}
```

To make the overlay view disappear as soon as the user touches the text field, set the `leftView` (or `rightView`) property to `nil` when editing begins. Just make sure to set it to point to your custom view again when editing ends.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.textField.leftView = nil;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.textField.leftView = self.customView;
}
```

**Edit**

A more generalized approach would be to simply toggle the mode on editing beginning and ending, which would eliminate the need to maintain a reference to the overlay view.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing;
}
```

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case.

Comment: Can you think of a system UI control that matches this pattern of hiding and showing a side view? I'm trying to find some justification for the default behavior being "expected."

Comment: @Justin Not sure I completely followed your question. Is there some specific issue you're unable to resolve?

Comment: I can see that `UITextField` does this, but I'm unconvinced that it _should_. I'm looking for any example, from the OS or an Apple app, that exhibits the default `UITextField` side view pattern of hiding the side view after a character has been entered. If I can find one, then this is most likely "expected" behavior. If I cannot, and most apps exhibit what I consider to be the _predictable_ and _preferred_ pattern of hiding when the field begins editing, then it's fair to file a bug report.

Comment: (Also, this has no bearing on the bounty, which I'm granting this second. I just want to make sure your answer reflects the conclusion we reach about expected behavior.)

Comment: @Justin I looked around a bit and couldn't find a counterexample. I think this is worth at the very least a documentation bug report, given that the precise behavior isn't clearly specified.

Comment: I've [filed it as a product bug report](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5790630466813952) rather than a documentation bug report given that the behavior has no precedent and contradicts what `UITextFieldDelegate` considers to be "editing." Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code with UITextFieldViewModeAlways and assign padding with as par star image width.

Put this code in viewDidLoad method

```
    UIImageView *iView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@" "]];
    [UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil].leftView = iView;
```

It will manage place holder text as well as textField text with left padding.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: The question asks how to hide the image, not offset it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set Mode of `textfield` after that it will work perfect. So use this one

```
leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

instead of

```
leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing;
```

Comment: I need to use leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing...(because the star button should be displayed UNLESS user edit text)
That's the problem!

Answer (score -2):

create leftview

```
     UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
      textField.leftView = paddingView;
      textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

      and you can add UIImageView on this paddingView for your star.png 
       UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"]];
    img.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0,5, 20);
    [paddingView adsubview:img];
```